# C# User input appearing below and not beside in request line

Tags: input

So I'm writing my first real project for an assignment, and although it is doing what it's supposed to, I need to make it look more appealing. More specifically, when it prompts the user to enter the length and width, the user input is appearing in a new line (write below the "Enter Length/Width of Lawn:". How can i make the user input appear Beside the question? Thanks for your help!

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

namespace A2P1Lawn
{
    public class Lawn
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 25, b = 35, c = 50;
            double area, numWeeks, option1, option2, option3;

            WriteLine("Enter the Lawn's Length:");
            double length = double.Parse(ReadLine());

            WriteLine("Enter the Lawn's Width:");
            double width = double.Parse(ReadLine());
            string amtDue;
            numWeeks = 20;
            area = length * width;
            WriteLine();
            if (area < 400)
            {
                option1 = a * numWeeks;
                amtDue = option1.ToString("C2");
                WriteLine("For a {0} by {1} Lawn and an Area of {2} Square Feet, the Weekly Fee Would Come to: $25", length, width, area);
                WriteLine("For the 20-Week Season, the Total Amount Due Would Come to " + amtDue);
                WriteLine();

            }
            else if (area > 400 && area < 600)
            {
                option2 = b * numWeeks;
                amtDue = option2.ToString("C2");
                WriteLine("For a {0} by {1} Lawn and an Area of {2} Square Feet, the Weekly Fee Would Come to: $35", length, width, area);
                WriteLine("For the 20-Week Season, the Total Amount Due Would Come to " + amtDue);
                WriteLine();

            }
            else
            {
                option3 = c * numWeeks;
                amtDue = option3.ToString("C2");
                WriteLine("For a {0} by {1} Lawn and an Area of {2} Square Feet, the Weekly Fee Would Come to: $35", length, width, area);
                WriteLine("For the 20-Week Season, the Total Amount Due Would Come to " + amtDue);
                WriteLine();

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcom to StackOverflow. Would you please first learn to format your question properly? [How to format your code properly in OS](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). It's really NOT easy to read your question. And also add which language you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code in question:

```
WriteLine("Enter the Lawn's Length:");
double length = double.Parse(ReadLine());
```

You are using `Console.WriteLine()` to output your prompt text. This command will output text plus a newline character that moves your cursor to the next line.

To keep the cursor on the same line, simply use `Console.Write()`, ex:

```
Write("Enter the Lawn's Length:");
double length = double.Parse(ReadLine());
```

This will keep your input cursor on the same line as the output text.